# SQLite3 OperationalError: Table XYZ has no column named ABC

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am new to peewee, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I have searched on Google and in the peewee cookbook, but found no solution so far.

So, I have the following models to four of my DB tables:

```
class games_def(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = dbmgr.DB

class users_def(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    first_name = TextField()
    last_name = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = dbmgr.DB

class sessions(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    game = ForeignKeyField(games_def, related_name = 'sessions')
    user = ForeignKeyField(users_def, related_name = 'sessions')
    comment = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = dbmgr.DB

class world_states(Model):
    session = ForeignKeyField(sessions)
    time_step = IntegerField()
    world_state = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = dbmgr.DB
```

Using these models I connect to an SQLite3 DB via peewee, which works fine.
After the connection has been established I do the following in my main Python code:

```
models.world_states.create(session = 1, time_step = 1)
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table world_states has no column named session_id
```

That is basically correct, the table world_state does indeed not contain such a column.
However, I cannot find any reference to "session_id" in my code at all.

Whe does peewee want to use that "session_id" colum name?
Do I miss something essentially here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a `ForeignKeyField()` peewee expects to use a column ending in `_id` based on their own name. Your `wold_states.session` field thus results in an column named `session_id`.

You can override this by setting `db_column` for that field:

```
class world_states(Model):
    session = ForeignKeyField(sessions, db_column='session')
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks Martijn!  The only thing I would add would be that if you created your table then added a field, peewee will not "automatically" add the column on your database table.  This must be done manually.

Comment: @coleifer: adjusted the wording.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much @MartijnPieters for this. After FOUR agonizing days I finally figured out my problem. I had the same thing going on and I checked the docs but the way they have it written out confused me and I had no idea db_column was to actually specify which column to point to.